# What is the definition of 'The System of all positive properties is compatible'?

Tags: goedel, existence-of-god

A sentence at the end of goedel's 1970 proof of god's existence is:

The possibility of god's existence means
'The System of all positive properties is compatible'

But without knowledge what compatibility of a system of properties is I crash in following the proof.

I failed to find that missing definition though I googled very hard.

I only found compatibility between pairs of objects what I'm already familiar with like plug and socket e.g.

help welcome

Comment: See [Gödel’s Ontological Argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-arguments/#GodOntArg); the key concept is that of *positive property*. Using specific axioms and definitions he proves "Theorem 1: If a property is positive, then it is consistent, i.e., possibly exemplified. Corollary 1: The property of being God-like is consistent." Thus, IMO "is compatible" means *consistent*, i.e. without contradiction.

Comment: Maybe you have to check your text... :)

Comment: See [Melvin Fitting](http://www.robotics.stanford.edu/~epacuit/talks/lmh-fitting-gg.pdf): "Leibniz attempted to prove that perfections are mutually compatible, basing his proof on the idea that perfections can only be purely positive
qualities and so none can negate the others. For Godel, rather than proving any two perfections could apply to the same object, Godel assumes the positive properties are closed under conjunction. This turns out to be a critical assumption." This is "formalized" by Godel in his AXIOM 3: "The conjunction of any collection of positive properties is positive."

Comment: based on your hints I try a definition: 'The System of all positive properties is compatible' iff 'P(x1)&....&P(xn) => P(x1&....&xn)'

Comment: This might help from the math stack exchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100230/gödels-ontological-argument-why-are-positive-properties-possible#1100245

Comment: A System of n positive properties φ1 ... φn is compatible iff P(φ1) & ... & P(φn) => P(φ1 & ... & φn)